# Ext-JS remove component gotcha

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a component acts like a table row, called flightLegComponent like so:

```
[ flight leg component ] [-] [+]

[ flight leg component] [-] [+]
```

...

when the [-] button is pressed, that component is meant to be removed from the parent panel.

I have added a listener to the [-] button, and in the listener, i call

```
this.remove(theFlightLegComponent);
```

where '**this**' is the parent component.

This throws an exception, apparently, you can not remove components inside the event handler... What is the proper way to remove it? invoke a method after a delay?

New:

The panels are structured so:

```
_flightLegRow: function(removable) {

    var flightLegInput = new xx.yy.zz.search.FlightLegInput({
        columnWidth: .8
    });

    var legId = 'flightLeg-' + this.legs++;

    var c = {

        border: 0,

        width: '90%',

        layout: 'column',

        id: legId,

        items: [

            flightLegInput,

            {
                columnWidth: .2,
                margin: 10,
                border: 0,
                layout: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: '-',
                    disabled: !removable,
                    listeners: {
                        click: Ext.Function.bind(function() {

                            //debugger;
                            this.remove(legId, true);
                        }, this)
                    }
                },{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: '+',
                    listeners: {
                        click: Ext.Function.bind(function(){
                            this.add(this._flightLegRow(true));
                        }, this)
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]

    };

    return c;

}
```

Comment: I have posted the same question in the extjs forum, its been a week and no answer yet! For anyone who is deciding between DOJO and ExtJS, choose DOJO! While ExtJS might on the surface look nice and pretty, when you delve into code and want to do something more complicated, you will have to write some of the most convoluted code you'll ever likely to write. ExtJS is definitely one of the most awkward frameworks I have ever touched. I have used dojo for a while and can truely say that dojo is miles ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove components in event handlers you need to remember to pass the proper scope.  If you are removing the component it may be invoking the parents autoDestroy config witch may delete it entirely and can cause null pointer exceptions.  I'm guessing the button handler's function is being called in the scope of the button and it's throwing an exception this.remove is undefined.  Any code or exception message would be helpful to pinpoint the problem.

```
new Ext.button.Button({
    handler: function(){this.remove......},
    scope: this
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you shold be using for the button:
b.ownerCt will be theFlightLegComponent and its ownerCt will the panel that contains theFlightLegComponent, in this way you can remove it.

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: '-',
    disabled: !removable,
    handler: function(b) {
        b.ownerCt.ownerCt.remove(legId, true);
    }
}
```